# SQL Server 2014 - Finding the period of activity between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sqldatetime

I have a table called Device where the device status has got logged when it mode is changed

```
CREATE TABLE MSTR.DEVICE_STATUS_HISTORY
(device_id int, MODE varchar(5) ,CHANGED_TIME datetime);

insert into MSTR.DEVICE_STATUS_HISTORY 
(DEVICE_ID,MODE,CHANGED_TIME)
values (17,'AUTO','2015-03-21 19:30:16.440'),
(17,'MANUAL','2015-03-21 22:20:45.880'),
(17,'AUTO','2015-03-24 11:58:18.990'),
(33,'MANUAL','2015-03-22 17:57:26.670'),
(33,'AUTO','2015-03-24 18:05:59.483 '),
(33,'MANUAL','2015-03-24 19:26:16.210'),
(33,'AUTO','2015-03-25 15:41:14.663 ');
```

The requirement to find the hours , minutes and seconds of auto and manual of a device during a period of time the parameter is passed

For E.g. I would like to get the auto/manual period from `22-03-2015 08:00:00` to `23-03-2015 16:45:35` ... Can any one help on this to write a query.

Result I m expecting is

```
Device Status  Hours minutes Seconds
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
17 --> Auto     5  Hours 10 Minutes  2 seconds
17--> Manual    2  Hours 11 Minutes 10 Seconds
33--> Auto      8  Hours 10 Minutes  2 seconds
33--> Manual   12  Hours 11 Minutes 10 Seconds
```

(The hours , minutes and seconds is for just an example will not match with the

Comment: I would recommend using `DATETIME2(3)` over `DATETIME` since the latter has some pretty severe limitations (date range, accuracy only 3.33ms etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Using [DATEPART](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp)

```
SELECT  DEVICE_ID
        ,MODE
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, CHANGED_TIME)) + ' Hours' AS Hours
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE, CHANGED_TIME)) + ' Minutes' AS Minutes 
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(SECOND, CHANGED_TIME)) + ' Seconds' AS Seconds 
FROM MSTR.DEVICE_STATUS_HISTORY
WHERE CHANGED_TIME <= '2015-03-22 08:00:00'
AND CHANGED_TIME >= '2015-03-21 16:45:35'
```

Comment: **Result I m expecting is Device Status Hours minutes Seconds

17 --> Auto 5 Hours 10 Minutes 2 seconds

17--> Manual 2 Hours 11 Minutes 10 Seconds

33--> Auto 8 Hours 10 Minutes 2 seconds

33--> Manual 12 Hours 11 Minutes 10 Seconds

(The hours , minutes and seconds is for just an example will not match with the**

Comment: @UvarajVijayan: please ***STOP*** writing everything in ***BOLD!***

Comment: The query above will not give me the duration . Duration of the status will be the lead of next row hours,minutes and seconds - this rows hours ,minutes and seconds .